# gtkmm and the system clipboard

Tags: gtk, clipboard, signals, gtkmm

I am wondering if there is a signal anywhere in gtkmm that is emitted when the system clipboard contents change/someone copies text.  I looked into the gtk docs and it seems the only signal emitted by the Gtk::Clipboard object is the owner_changed signal. To be more specific, I don't care who changes the system clipboard whether it be my app (which it wont be) or the user.

My only other option to implement this is to loop and keep checking the clipboard for a change.  Was hoping there was a more efficient means of accomplishing this.

Anyone know of a signal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this [example](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-clipboard-examples.html.en#sec-clipboard-example-ideal).  I did not compile and run it, but I think it is indicating that the "owner_changed" signal will do what you want.